# .Net Could not load type from assembly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have Asp.Net MVC 4 project called **Ba.Web** and have another class library project called **Ba.Framework**.

In Ba.Framework  previously have been class called AdminAuthorizeAttribute with namespace
**Ba.Framework.Filters** but now its totally deleted.

Very often at runtime i get this error

***Could not load type 'Ba.Framework.Filters.AdminAuthorizeAttribute' from assembly 'Ba.Framework, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.***

Only rebuild helps, but after some time i still get this error. How i can even get this error if i deleted this class and there is no usages anywhere.
I tried to delete temp Asp.Net files, 100 times cleared solution, but still...

Comment: Try clearing your `bin` directory

Comment: What is the location of the binary version of Ba.Framework that Ba.Web is accessing?

Comment: Yes, problems was in bin directory

Answer (score 0):

It is like you hooked lib (Ba.Framework) not proper version. Check how did u make reference to Ba.Framework from same solution or from browse lib file.

To solve such problem try:
 1. Add lib exactly to your project and check write version of library.
 2. Do search via your solution for Ba.Framework.Filters.AdminAuthorizeAttribute, it can be in same namespace in anouther project.
 3. Check you Ba.Framework under "show all files explorer flag" for Ba.Framework.Filters.AdminAuthorizeAttribute, maybe it is hiden
 4. Clear all solution
 5. Rebuild solution

Last chance, this lib is autogenerated by code.